# How to rock the universe without provoking intergalactic war?

Tags: culture, civilization, music, space-warfare

Even in the distant future stupidly loud rock metal is being played and enjoyed by many humans, even those that finds it irritating still recognise it as a form of music alright... officially it's noise pollution but nonetheless its human thing or maybe not.
The universe is filled with many advanced civilizations, some are far superior to us but so far none has shown hostility to us. I believe exchanging cultures with them is a good way for us to better understand each other, so how can we make loud noises and aim dazzling lasers at them without being seen as provocation? We just want to make love not war.

Comment: Three words: Ultimate Bluegrass Ramble. All sophonts can appreciate great bluegrass, so they can participate.

Comment: Have you read [Claws that Catch](http://baencd.freedoors.org/Discs/Baen%2016/index.htm)? If not, you should; it seems relevant to your question. (Ahem: which is a bit of a spoiler, but too bad. Read the other three books first, though; Claws is the fourth in the series. All four are available for free at the link, and [VotSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_of_the_Space_Bubble) is definitely worth reading if you haven't...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no noise in the universe because sound only travels through materials. Once sound hits the vacuum of space, no one would hear anything. You'll kill the ears (and maybe the rest of the person) of everyone on Earth, but no one else.

As for flashing lights - people might just assume that you're doing some heavy nuclear testing on Earth. As long as you don't beam high intensity radiation at any other inhabited solar systems you should be ok. When I say high-intensity I mean comparable to a gamma ray burst. I think precision hits on inhabited solar systems is what would really raise red flags.

Answer (score 2):

**Explain it to them beforehand and patiently understand if they don't want it**

If we want to exchange our cultures with other intelligent beings, it'd behoove us to tell them beforehand what exactly we're doing. Holding a rock concert at decibels which are hazardous to human hearing which lots of flashing lights seems like a not-great idea and something which could be mistaken for a rallying cry to battle. So we don't just hold a rock concert. First, we explain to the aliens that we'd like them to sample and understand our culture, so we're going to hold a concert. We hand out little pamphlets explaining the history of rock and what the nature of a rock concert is. Finally, we also check with their biologists beforehand to make sure that the noise level will be fine.

And, should they decide that the rock concert and culture isn't for them, we understand that perhaps we don't need to 'rock the universe', and that while human culture is good for humans, not everyone need rock'n'roll in their soul.

Comment: My question is inspired by the evolution of tribal dance, hunter gathers used loud music for celebration but prior to that it is generally used for warding off wild animals and other unwanted clans. I think every civilization started similarly so maybe we all shares something in our roots.